# How to slow down assigned scrollwheel action?

Tags: autohotkey

I've assigned a couple of hotkeys to wheeldown and wheelup. It works, but I'd like to slow down the scrolling action. Is there some way to do that?

```
1::wheeldown

2::wheelup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ellen, does this help?

```
2::MouseClick, WheelUp, , , 1
1::MouseClick, WheelDown, , , 1
```

Comment: Hi Robert, That doesn't seem to make a difference. Also, is that supposed to be before or after the key assignments? I tried it in both positions.

Comment: It defines the Nr. of lines to scroll up/down. I changed the code so it uses this with 1 and 2

Comment: Now it works. Thanks! Could you please explain what you did by adding MouseClick, for my future understanding?

Comment: Is there a way to slow it down even more? I've tried using .5 instead of 1, but it stops working altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use a time delay (which is easier to configure because it's in milliseconds.  In this example, it's set to 2 seconds (2 thousand milliseconds).

```
1::scrollup(2000)
2::scrolldown(2000)

scrolldown(freq) {
    static time=A_TickCount
    new_time := A_TickCount

    if(new_time - time > freq) {
        SendInput {WheelDown}
        time := new_time
    }
}

scrollup(freq) {
    static time=A_TickCount
    new_time := A_TickCount

    if(new_time - time > freq) {
        SendInput {WheelUp}
        time := new_time
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried changing the numbers in the first part, but that had no effect on the number of lines per keypress. As far as the second part, I really don't know what to do with that. What is happening so far is that I can't seem to go any slower than what I have specified in Mouse Properties (Control Panel) as the number of lines per click. For the purposes of this script only, I would like to go at less than that rate.

Comment: Did you try increasing it?  If you do something like 10000, it'll only go every 10 seconds, or 3600000 would be every hour (while holding the button).

Comment: I want to slow it down in terms of lines per click, not actual time. Sorry for the confusion.